# look up column error

Tags: powershell, custom-list, lookup-column

1. I am getting into a null array - `$spList = $webobj.Lists["Studentlist1"]`
2. Exception calling "update" with "0" argument(s): "This lookup field cannot enforce a relationship behavior because it is not indexed.

I am getting above two errors when i run the below powershell script to create a lookup column in a list "Studentlist1" calling "ID" column from a parent list "Studentlist"

```
#To which site u want to create the list 
$spWeb=Get-SPWeb -Identity http://XYZ

#List type or template 
$spTemplate = $spWeb.ListTemplates["Custom List"]

#Get all the lists to the listcollection
$spListCollection=$spWeb.Lists

#adding the new list to the list collection
$spListCollection.Add("Studentlist1","Studentlist1",$spTemplate)

#get the path of subsite and sitecollecion 
$path = $spWeb.url.trim()

#get the list to the list object
$spList = $spWeb.GetList("$path/Lists/Studentlist1")

#adding the field type(Number) to the list
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Number
$spList.Fields.Add("SNo",$spFieldType,$false)

#adding the field type(Text) to the list
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text
$spList.Fields.Add("SName",$spFieldType,$false)

$ParentList = $spWeb.Lists.item("Studentlist")
$spList = $WebObj.Lists["Studentlist1"]
$spList.Fields.AddLookup("ChildLookupField",$ParentList.id,$false)
$spChildListLookupField = $spList.Fields["ChildLookupField"]
$spChildListLookupField.LookupField = $ParentList.Fields["ID"]
$spChildListLookupField.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior]::Restrict
$spChildListLookupField.Update()

$Views = $spList.Views["All Items"]
$Views.ViewFields.Add("SNo")
$Views.ViewFields.Add("SName")
$Views.ViewFields.Add("ChildLookupField")


$Views.Update()
```

Answer (score 2):

**For first issue**

Replace

```
#adding the new list to the list collection
$spListCollection.Add("Studentlist1","Studentlist1",$spTemplate)

#get the path of subsite and sitecollecion 
$path = $spWeb.url.trim()

#get the list to the list object
$spList = $spWeb.GetList("$path/Lists/Studentlist1")
```

With

```
#adding the new list to the list collection
$lstId = $spListCollection.Add("Studentlist1","Studentlist1",$spTemplate)

#get the list to the list object
$spList = $spWeb.Lists[[System.GUID]($lstId)]
```

**For second issue**

Replace

```
$spList.Fields.AddLookup("ChildLookupField",$ParentList.id,$false)
$spChildListLookupField = $spList.Fields["ChildLookupField"]
$spChildListLookupField.LookupField = $ParentList.Fields["ID"]
$spChildListLookupField.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior]::Restrict
$spChildListLookupField.Update()
```

with

```
$spList.Fields.AddLookup("ChildLookupField",$ParentList.id,$false)
$spChildListLookupField = $spList.Fields["ChildLookupField"]
$spChildListLookupField.LookupField = $ParentList.Fields["ID"]
$spChildListLookupField.Indexed = $true
$spChildListLookupField.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior]::Restrict
$spChildListLookupField.Update()
```

The field has to be indexed before creating relationship delete behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The second issue is resolved by adding indexed to true. but i am still having first error.         Cannot index into a null array$spList = $WebObj.Lists["Studentlist1"].      You told me to check the list title is Studentlist1 right ??   I am creating this list using this code only right. how could it have different name.

Comment: @mak please try updated answer